# OpenShift, MongoDB: Connexion without Port Forwarding

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I have an instance of MongoDB running on OpenShift. Without port forwarding, is it possible to connect from the local machine to the database using, say, OpenShift route or the IP address of the service? If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try [Creating a Headless Service](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/using_images/db_images/mysql.html#mysql-creating-headless-service)
 against connecting to mongodb ? Additionally refer [MongoDB](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/db_images/mongodb.html#overview).

I hope it help you.

Comment: I added `portalIP: None`, but I get this error: `No changes were applied to service mongodb. Make sure any new fields you may have added are supported API fields.`

Comment: I'm sorry, the reference was bad, refer [this](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html#headless-service-creation) for creating headless service.